# log4j and slf4j in single project - is this a good idea?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

In our project we have been using log4j for a long time. And it served our purposes well.

We have a need now to use a query builder, for database queries. We decided to try out either [querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com) or [jooq](http://www.jooq.org/). However, both of them seem to demand slf4j as a logging library.

I could simply include that as the maven dependency, but are there any pitfalls? Can log4j conflict with slf4j and generate some unpredicted behaviour?

Comment: slf4j is not an actual logging framework. It's only a **facade** for many actual logging frameworks, including log4j. So no, it's not a problem. It's probably even one of the most used combos. Read the doc. http://www.slf4j.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SLF4J website :

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade
>   or abstraction for various logging frameworks (e.g. java.util.logging,
>   logback, log4j) allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging
>   framework at deployment time.

So SLF4J is just a facade and will use log4j behind...